# multiple XMLHttpRequest display issue

Tags: javascript, html

I was successfully able to make multiple `XMLHttpRequest` and this is my code:

```
var index = ["status", "net"]
for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
  var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/" + index[i];
  let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("GET", url);
  http.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status == 200) {
       console.log(http.responseText);
       var respond = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
       console.log("respond is" + respond.name);
       console.log("respond is" + respond.dhcp_on);
       console.log("respond is" + respond.sn);

       document.getElementById('device-name').value = respond.name;
   }
}

   http.send();
}
```

I am getting the proper value in the console but as I am trying to display the value in my input element with id (device-name) I get `undefined`.

FYI this is how my console log is looking like

```
{"name":"DEV 1","sn":"123456789","uptime":123} 
    respond isDEV 1 
    respond isundefined 
    respond is123456789 

{"dhcp_on":true,"ip":"1.2.3.4","mask":"1.2.3.4","gw":"1.2.3.4","dns":"1.2.3.4"} 
    respond isundefined 
    respond istrue 
    respond isundefined
```

Could anyone explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is working properly for me as it is i just double tested it to make sure i didn't miss anything while typing the question 
my Jason object is ({"name":"DEV 1","sn":"123456789","uptime":123})
but i have no idea why it is giving me undefined when i am trying to display in on the html element !

Comment: How your HTML code looks like?

Comment: @LamisAbouzina - Please use the "edit" link to put that information in the question, properly formatted.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - No, string concatenation works just fine.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it is working fine i have no problem with the string here

Comment: yes just checked! and just saw your edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing to the same element repeatedly in a loop. The response to your **first** request has `name`:

```
{"name":"DEV 1","sn":"123456789","uptime":123}
```

but the response to your **second** response does not:

```
{"dhcp_on":true,"ip":"1.2.3.4","mask":"1.2.3.4","gw":"1.2.3.4","dns":"1.2.3.4"}
```

Since the loop does

```
document.getElementById('device-name').value = respond.name;
```

both times, you're **overwriting** the result of the first (which has the `name`) with the result of the second (which doesn't), exactly like this:

```js
const results = [
  {"name":"DEV 1","sn":"123456789","uptime":123},
  {"dhcp_on":true,"ip":"1.2.3.4","mask":"1.2.3.4","gw":"1.2.3.4","dns":"1.2.3.4"}
];
// (Using your loop structure and variable names)
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
  var respond = results[i];
  document.getElementById("device-name").value = respond.name;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="device-name">
```

You only want to set `device-name` when processing the first response, not the second. You can do that by checking `i`, or by checking whether `name` is in the response:

```js
const results = [
  {"name":"DEV 1","sn":"123456789","uptime":123},
  {"dhcp_on":true,"ip":"1.2.3.4","mask":"1.2.3.4","gw":"1.2.3.4","dns":"1.2.3.4"}
];
// (Using your loop structure and variable names)
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
  var respond = results[i];
  if ("name" in respond) {
    document.getElementById("device-name").value = respond.name;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="device-name">
```

In this case, `if ("name" in respond) {` could be `if (respond.hasOwnProperty("name")) {` or `if (respond.name !== undefined) {`, whatever you prefer. `in` checks the whole prototype chain, but the chain is quite short when the object came from `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Great! got to know about `"name" in respond` first time

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thank you that is helpful, i only added an if condition before get element by ID to check i name is in my respond and it worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

so by simply adding an if condition to check if the id i want to display is in my returned object or not as @T.J. Crowder explained it worked perfectly

```
var index = ["status", "net"];
        for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
            var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/" + index[i];
            let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open("GET", url);
            http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status == 200) {
                    console.log(http.responseText);
                    var respond = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

                    if ("name" in respond) {
                    document.getElementById('device-name').value = respond.name;
                }}
            }

            http.send();
        }
```